# How would I create an if statement for strings based on multiple conditions in R?

Tags: r, string, if-statement

So I want to create a new column in my dataset that would be "1" if True and "0" if false.

My data is setup similar to this:

```
v1 v2 v3
a  b  c
b  b  c
d  b  c
```

Let's say that I want my if statement to be setup to where if v1 equals a, b, or c, then the new column would be 1. Under this new condition, I would want my new dataset to look like this.

```
v1 v2 v3 v4
a  b  c  1
b  b  c  1
d  b  c  0
```

How would I go about setting this up? Hopefully I made sense explaining this, I tried to simplify as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need a fixed match, use `%in%` for more than one elements, would return a logical vector, which can be coerced to binary with `+`

```
 df1$v4 <- +(df1$v1 %in% c('a', 'b', 'c'))
```

Or use `as.integer`

```
df1$v4 <- as.integer(df1$v1 %in% c('a', 'b', 'c'))
```

---

If we are looking for substring matches, use `grepl`

```
df1$v4 <- as.integer(grepl("(a|b|c)$", df1$v1))
```

Comment: What does the + sign do in this case?

Comment: Worked like a charm thanks! To add to this a little, lets say the one of the 'a, b, c's' can have up to 4 chars in front of them, example 'xxxx c'.  How could I adjust the code the ignore the 'xxxx' and just look for the 'c'? If that makes sense.

Comment: @Reeza it is a hacky way to coerce too binarry from logical

Comment: @MaxH. is it only to loook for 'c' orr 'a' and 'b' as well

Comment: @akrun I would still be looking for a, b, and c as before, but just adjusting to ignore any characters before the actual 'c' in this case.